# Why does code fail with "pointer being freed was not allocated"?

Tags: c++, vector

I have an error

```
12 SIZE: 3 CAPACITY: 4
12 SIZE: 4 CAPACITY: 4
DESTRUCTOR
proj1(53055,0x10121c580) malloc: *** error for object 0x600001ac1110: pointer being freed was not allocated
proj1(53055,0x10121c580) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
zsh: abort      /Users/mascai/root_folder/dev/projects/03_cpp_examples/02_ide/build/proj1
```

My code:

```
template<class T>
class Vector {
public:
    Vector() = default;
    Vector(size_t size) : size_(size), capacity_(size * 2) {
        data_= new T[capacity_];
    }
    Vector(size_t size, const T val) : size_(size), capacity_(size * 2) {
        data_= new T[capacity_];
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size_; ++i) {
            data_[i] = val;
        }
    }
    Vector(const Vector& other) {
        data_ = other.data_;
        size_ = other.size_;
        capacity_ = other.capacity_;
    }
    const Vector& operator=(const Vector<T>& other) {
        data_ = other.data_;
        size_ = other.size_;
        capacity_ = other.capacity_;
        return *this;
    }
    ~Vector() {
        cout << "DESTRUCTOR" << endl;
        if (data_) {
            delete[] data_;
        }
        size_ = 0;
        capacity_ = 0;
    }

    T operator[](size_t idx) const {
        if (idx < size_) {
            return *(data_ + idx);
        }
        throw std::invalid_argument("Inde out of range");
    }

    void push_back(const T& val) {
        size_ += 1;
        if (size_ > capacity_) {
            capacity_ *= 2;
            T* new_data = new T[capacity_];
            for (int i = 0; i < size_ - 1; ++i) {
                *new_data++ = *data_++; 
            }
            delete[] data_;
            data_ = new_data; 
        } else {
            *(data_ + size_ - 1) = val;
        }
    }

    size_t size() const {
        return size_;
    }

    size_t capacity() const {
        return capacity_;
    }

private:
    T* data_ = nullptr;
    size_t size_ = 0;
    size_t capacity_ = 0;
};


int main() {
    Vector<int> v(2, 111);
    assert(v[0] == 111);
    v.push_back(12);
    cout << v[2] << " SIZE: " << v.size() << " CAPACITY: " << v.capacity() << endl;
    v.push_back(12);
    cout << v[3] << " SIZE: " << v.size() << " CAPACITY: " << v.capacity() << endl;
    v.push_back(13);
}
```

Looks like the problem deals with invalid usage of delete. What should I fix?

Comment: Focus your eyeballs on this line in your copy constructor: `data_ = other.data_;`. Think about what it means. As in logically. Keep staring at it until you see the obvious problem. Do the same with the same line in the assignment operator. Do you  understand that as a result of this, both pointers have the same value? And they belong to different objects? And each object's destructor will try to destroy it? Does this make sense to you?

Comment: Side note: [additional diagnostics](https://godbolt.org/z/bnE4ETeTa) give more good intel on the problem.

Comment: Side note on writing assignment operators: the [Copy and Swap Idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3279543/4581301) makes assigning dead easy and nearly foolproof. It might not produce the most efficient assignment operator, but it's so hard to get wrong it's the perfect place to start, and profiling will quickly tell you igf you need a faster, more complicated option.

Comment: Arthur O'Dwyer explains everything you need to know—and supplies source code for a "roll-your-own" vector class—in this excellent talk from CppCon 2019: [Back to Basics: RAII and the Rule of Zero](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Qgd9B1KuMQ). Here is the [cheat sheet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Qgd9B1KuMQ&t=40m58s) with all the source code.

Comment: In the destructor, `size_ = 0;` and `capacity_ = 0;` are pointless; the object is being destroyed, and these data members will not exist after the destructor returns.

Comment: `if (data_) {delete[] data_; }` -- There is no need for the `if (data_)` as it is perfectly legal to call `delete` on a `nullptr`.  Just simply `delete [] data_;` with no `if` is all that needs to be done.

Comment: [What is the rule of 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).  As mentioned, your copy constructor and assignment operator are incorrect, as they do not actually make a copy of the memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a new element and need to allocate more memory, you have this unfortunate sequence:

```cpp
// before the loop, data_ points at the memory you allocated
for (size_t i = 0; i < size_ - 1; ++i) {
    *new_data++ = *data_++; // increasing data_
}
delete[] data_;             // UB: here data_ points somewhere else
```

When you `delete[] data_` afterwards, it does not hold the original address, and your program therefore has undefined behavior. `new_data` is of course affected in the same way.

Another important detail: If `size_ > capacity_` is `true` in `push_back`, you never store `val`.

Suggested fix:

```cpp
#include <algorithm> // std::move

void push_back(const T& val) {
    if (size_ >= capacity_) {
        auto new_cap = capacity_ ? capacity_ * 2 : 1;        
        T* new_data = new T[new_cap];
        std::move(data_, data_ + size_, new_data);
        delete[] data_;
        // don't change capacity until you've successfully new'd
        capacity_ = new_cap;
        data_ = new_data;
    }
    // and don't change the size until after a successful new either:
    data_[size_++] = val; // always stores `val` 
}
```

I also recommend that you `delete` your copy constructor and copy assignment operator for now. They do not work since they only copy the *pointer* to the data and do not allocate new memory and copy the data to that memory. If you had used the copy constructor or copy assignment operator, you'd have more than one object owning the same memory and you would have gotten a "double free" when the second object tried to `delete[]` the allocated memory.

Note: You don't need to check if `data_` is a `nullptr` in the destructor. just `delete[] data_;` - it's safe to `delete[] nullptr;`.

Comment: The other fix in this answer is exception safety; if `new T[capacity_ * 2]` throws an exception the data members reflect the state of the object before the call to `puah_back`. As originally written, the values of both `size_` and `capacity_` after an exception are wrong, because the array hasn't been reallocated but both of those data members have been changed.

Comment: @PeteBecker Indeed. I noticed this detail after a while and moved the `capacity_ *= 2;` line to after the `new`.  A pedantic version would check if the type is actually `is_nothrow_move_assignable` too and adjust for that, but... nah.

Comment: The general principle being that you do anything that could throw an exception **before** you change any data members. That should be a habit.

Answer (score 2):

The error is occurring in your `push_back` function when you are calling `delete` on `_data`:

```cpp
void push_back(const T& val) {
    size_ += 1;
    if (size_ > capacity_) {
        capacity_ *= 2;
        T* new_data = new T[capacity_];
        for (int i = 0; i < size_ - 1; ++i) {
            *new_data++ = *data_++; 
        }
        delete[] data_;
        data_ = new_data; 
    } else {
        *(data_ + size_ - 1) = val;
    }
}
```

Because you are using the `++` operator on the pointers `new_data` and `data_`, you are moving the pointer from the start of the elements to the end. Therefore, your pointers `new_data` and `data_` are pointing to the wrong spots in memory, and when you try to delete them you will get an error.

To fix this, instead of using the  `++` operator, try using pointer arithmetic *inside* parenthesis like so:

```cpp
void push_back(const T& val) {
    size_ += 1;
    if (size_ > capacity_) {
        capacity_ *= 2;
        T* new_data = new T[capacity_];
        for (int i = 0; i < size_ - 1; ++i) {
            *(new_data + i) = *(data_ + i); // change
        }
        delete[] data_;
        data_ = new_data;
    }
    else {
        *(data_ + size_ - 1) = val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: Instead of `*(new_data + i) = *(data_ + i);` make it `newdata[i] = data[i];` or even `newdata[i] = std::move(data[i]);`. Similarly `*(data_ + size_ - 1) = val;` could just be `data_[size_ - 1] = val;`

Comment: The version of `push_back` in this answer has a subtle error. It fails when called on a default-constructed `Vector`. That's because the default `capacity_` is zero. Doubling that inside function `push_back` still gives you zero.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does code fail with "pointer being freed was not allocated"?

This occurs because you incremented the value of `data_` in function `push_back`, before calling operator delete on it.

##### Function `push_back` fails for three reasons

1. The default constructor sets `capacity_` to zero. When function `push_back_` doubles this, it is still zero.
2. The pointers `data_` and `new_data` should not be incremented in the loop. For the loop, you should use temporary pointers instead. Better still, call `std::copy` to copy the array elements.
3. If the array is reallocated, then `val` is not stored in the array.

Here is one way to fix those errors.

```cpp
    void push_back(const T& val) {
        size_ += 1;
        if (size_ > capacity_) {
            // check for zero capacity
            std::size_t new_capacity{ capacity_ ? capacity_ * 2u : 2u };
            T* new_data = new T[new_capacity];
            auto d{ data_ };     // use temporary pointers to copy 
            auto n{ new_data };  // the array elements
            for (int i = 0; i < size_ - 1; ++i) {
                *n++ = *d++;
            }
            delete[] data_;
            data_ = new_data;
            capacity_ = new_capacity;
        }
        // Store `val` in all cases.
        *(data_ + size_ - 1) = val;
    }
```

##### Copy constructor

Here is the copy constructor as written.

```cpp
    Vector(const Vector& other) {
        data_ = other.data_;
        size_ = other.size_;
        capacity_ = other.capacity_;
    }
```

All it does is copy the member variables from `other` to `*this`. Such a copy is called a *memberwise copy*. That is what the *compiler-supplied, default copy constructor* would have done if you had not written any copy constructor at all!

Member variable `data_` points to a dynamically allocated array stored on the heap. When you copy the value of pointer `data_`, you are not copying the array itself. There is still only one array out on the heap. After the copy constructor has executed, however, there will be two pointers that point to it. The first is `this->data_` and the second is `other.data_`.

When you copy a pointer, without copying the thing it points to, you have made a *shallow copy*. When you copy a pointer *and* the object it points to, you have made a *deep copy*.

The result of making a shallow copy is to create cross-linked vectors. The data stored in one vector can be retrieved using the copy!

Here is an example that uses the `Vector` defined in the OP.

```cpp
int main()
{
    Vector<int> v(2, 111);
    assert(v[0] == 111);
    auto v2{ v };
    v2[0] = 0;           // A modification to vector `v2`
    assert(v[0] == 0);   // shows up in vector `v`!
    std::cout 
        << "v[0]: " << v[0] 
        << ", v2[0]: " << v2[0] << "\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

This program crashes with a double-free error. Before it does, however, it outputs this text, which shows that the two vectors are crosslinked.

```
v[0]: 0, v2[0]: 0

DESTRUCTOR
DESTRUCTOR
```

You can also see the double-free. The first call to the destructor of `v2` is fine. The array on the heap will be deleted. It is the second call to the destructor, when `v` is deallocated, that causes the double-free error.

The conclusion is that shallow copy leads to two errors:

1. cross-linked vectors
2. double-free errors

This fix is to perform a deep copy in the copy constructor.

```cpp
    Vector(const Vector& other)
        : data_{ new T[other.capacity_] }  // allocate a new array
        , size_{ other.size_ }
        , capacity_{ other.capacity_ }
    {
        // Call `std::copy` to copy array elements.
        if (other.data_)
            std::copy(other.data_, other.data_ + size_, this->data);
    }
```

##### Copy-and-swap assignment operator

A similar fix is needed in the copy-assignment operator.

The old-school method checks for self-assignment, so that the array on the heap is not deleted before it has been copied.

```cpp
    Vector& operator=(const Vector<T>& other) {
        if (this != &other)
        {
            auto p{ new T[other.capacity_] };
            delete[] data_;
            data_ = p;
            size_ = other.size_;
            capacity_ = other.capacity_;

            // Call `std::copy` to copy array elements.
            if (other.data_)
                std::copy(other.data_, other.data_ + size_, this->data_);
        }
        return *this;
    }
```

Note that the copy-assignment operator in the OP had an error. It return `T const&`, when it should return a reference `T&`. The function above corrects that.

A much simpler way to accomplish the same thing is to use the *copy-and-swap* idiom. This requires coding a noexcept `swap` function, but you probably should have one of those anyway. The implementation below uses a value parameter, which is initialized by making a copy of the argument that is supplied at the call site. That's the copy part.

The destructor for parameter `other` is invoked at the closing brace of this copy-assignment operator. That's when the old array is deleted.

```cpp
    void swap(Vector& other) noexcept {
        using std::swap;  // Allow ADL (argument-dependent lookup)
        swap(this->data_, other.data_);
        swap(this->size_, other.size_);
        swap(this->capacity_, other.capacity_);
    }
    friend void swap(Vector& a, Vector& b) noexcept {
        a.swap(b);
    }
    Vector& operator=(Vector other) noexcept {
        swap(other);
        return *this;
    }
```

##### Two versions of `operator[]`

You need to have two versions `operator[]`, one for constant objects, and the other for non-const objects.

In function `main` (above), the assignment `v2[0] = 0;` requires an operator that works on non-const objects. As the code in the OP does not have one, it was necessary to write one. In addition, I made several changes to the existing operator.

1. Subscripting operators generally return references, either const or non-const, so I made that change.
2. I replaced pointer arithmetic, e.g., `*(data_ + idx)`  with array subscripting.
3. I added function `check_subscript`. It should be automatically inlined in release builds.

Here is the result.

```cpp
private:
    void check_subscript(std::size_t const idx) const {
        if (idx >= size_)
            throw std::invalid_argument("Index out of range");
    }
public:
    T const& operator[](size_t idx) const {
        check_subscript(idx);
        return data_[idx];
    }

    T& operator[](size_t idx) {
        check_subscript(idx);
        return data_[idx];
    }
```

##### Default constructor

As written, the default constructor leaves `data_` with the value `nullptr`. It should probably allocate an array with `capacity_` zero.

Here's the fix.

```cpp
    Vector()
        : data_{ new T[0] }
        , size_{}
        , capacity_{}
    {}
```

##### Output

With these changes function `main` from the OP now runs correctly, producing the following output.

```
12 SIZE: 3 CAPACITY: 4
12 SIZE: 4 CAPACITY: 4
DESTRUCTOR
```

Comment: Re: _"As written, the default constructor leaves `data_` with the value `nullptr`. It should probably allocate an array with `capacity_` zero."_ - Why? Isn't `nullptr` perfect for a container with no capacity? The first thing it has to do when adding an element to the container is `new T[new_capacity]` anyway so why waste a `new T[0]`?

Comment: Consider the copy constructor and copy-assignment operators above. They both have special tests to check whether `data_` is `nullptr`. Without the special tests, the expression `other.data_ + size_` would be evaluated. When `data_` is guaranteed not be `nullptr`, those tests can be omitted. But I modified the language a bit, anyway.

Comment: Ok, but `if (other.data_)` could just be changed to `if (other.size_)` to get the best of both worlds then I guess.

Comment: Sure. That's a valid approach. But it is still a test, and it is needed for the same reason. You don't want to evaluate `other.data_ + size_` when `data_` is `nullptr`. With a guarantee that `data_` is not `nullptr`, there is no problem with `data_ + 0`.

Comment: Yeah, it's a test, but with that test you don't have to `new T[0]` to avoid `nullptr + 0zu`. Btw, [`nullptr + 0zu`](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#4.1) becomes just `nullptr` so you _could_ just skip the test _and_ skip `new T[0]`.

Comment: _[`nullptr + 0zu`](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#4.1) becomes just `nullptr`_ Thanks for link. I just learned something. And that means you are right: both the test and `new T[0]` can be avoided!